# Discord /commands 'This command is outdated, please try again in a few minutes'

Tags: javascript, discord

I have been trying to fix this issue for a while and cant find the right answer this is my code,

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");



module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('test')
    .setDescription('Get info about a user or a server!')
    .addStringOption(option =>
        option.setName('category')
            .setDescription('The gif category')
            .setRequired(true)
            .addChoices(
                { name: 'Funny', value: 'funny is funny' },
                { name: 'Meme', value: 'Meme is a meme' },
                { name: 'Movie', value: 'Movie is a Movie' },
            ))
    , 
    async execute(interaction) {
        interaction.options.getString('category');
        
    }
}
```

[Heres a pic of whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2diL.png)

Comment: I am also having this issue. It started when I added a string option to my slash command, but was working perfectly fine before that

Comment: Similar here, though I'm not sure what I did to break it. :( It's been hours now and has not fixed itself.

Comment: It should take at most an hour to sync. If it's been over an hour that sounds like a discord bug.

Answer (score 6):

I've seen this happen time to time. Discord takes some amount of time for slash commands to work their way into the system when you start up your code. If your code hits lots of guilds, it could take an hour. If you only specify one guild, it is usually fairly instant but in some cases it may take 5 min. Let your code run for 5-10 min and check back, it will probably fix this error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32718402)